# MySQL 5.7.14 - how to match a LIKE against a column that sometime contains '&nbsp;' instead of a space

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement with a LIKE. However, the column sometimes contains:

```
&nbsp;
```

which then does not match. An example:

```
ad_detail LIKE 'Personal Growth - 1'
```

Column ad_detail contains:

```
Personal Growth - 1 //matches
Personal Growth&nbsp;- 1 //does not match
Personal Growth -&nbsp;1 //does not match
Personal Growth&nbsp;-&nbsp;1 //does not match
```

How can I fix this to match in all instances please.

Comment: Just a note. MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year. Maybe it's worth considering upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` in MySQL has only two wildcards, one which matches any single character and one which matches any string of zero or more characters. These wildcards are `_` and `%` respectively.

You could do this:

```
ad_detail LIKE 'Personal Growth%- 1'
```

But this would have the unintended behavior of matching a lot of other strings that you don't want it to.

```
Personal Growth - 1 //matches
Personal Growth&nbsp;- 1 //matches
Personal Growth -&nbsp;1 //matches
Personal Growth&nbsp;-&nbsp;1 //matches
```

Probably matches things you don't to match:

```
Personal Growth-1 //matches because % matches zero characters
Personal Growth is good for you -1 //matches because % matches any string of characters
```

You probably want to use a regular expression:

```
ad_detail REGEXP 'Personal Growth( |&nbsp;)-( |&nbsp;)1'
```

Comment: This lead me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
REPLACE(at_award_description.ad_detail, '&nbsp;', ' ') LIKE ?
```

Where ? is any string that I am matching against (e.g., 'Personal Growth - 1').